# How to stop all idle EC2 instances using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have been trying to detect and shutdown AWS EC2 instances that are idle (<10% CPU).

Lambda code (set with IAM role AmazonEC2FullAccess):

```
import boto3
def put_cpu_alarm(instance_id):
    cloudWatch   = boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    cloudWatch.put_metric_alarm(
        AlarmName          = f'CPU_ALARM_{instance_id}',
        AlarmDescription   = 'Alarm when server CPU does not exceed 10%',
        AlarmActions       = ['arn:aws:automate:us-east-1:ec2:stop'],
        MetricName         = 'CPUUtilization',
        Namespace          = 'AWS/EC2' ,
        Statistic          = 'Average',
        Dimensions         = [{'Name': 'InstanceId', 'Value': instance_id}],
        Period             = 300,
        EvaluationPeriods  = 3,
        Threshold          = 10,
        ComparisonOperator = 'LessThanOrEqualToThreshold',
        TreatMissingData   = 'notBreaching'
    )
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    instance_id = event['detail']['instance-id']
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    instance = ec2.Instance(instance_id)
    put_cpu_alarm(instance_id)
```

​Event pattern in Cloudwatch Rule

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.ec2"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "EC2 Instance State-change Notification"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "state": [
      "running"
    ]
  }
}
```

Error I am getting,

```
[ERROR] KeyError: 'detail'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 19, in lambda_handler
    instance_id = event['detail']['instance-id']
```

Expecting result:

Detect and stop EC2 idle running instances.

Comment: Any time you get an error like this print out what you're getting in the `event` - it's obviously not what you're expecting.

Comment: Why an autoscaling groups is not sufficient and you are building a custom solution?

Comment: What's the point of the lambda function exactly? To create a new alarm every time a new EC2 instance is created?

Comment: All this doesn't make any sense! You can create a cloudwatch alarm for the EC2 instance and when it's less than 10% for $time, stop the instance(select from EC2 actions in cloudwatch). Why do you need a lambda??

Answer (score 1):

The `event` parameter passed to an AWS Lambda function contains multiple `Records`. You can see this by debugging the function with `print(event)`.

Therefore, your code should loop through each `Record`:

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  for record in event['Records']:
    instance_id = record['detail']['instance-id']
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How are you able to debug the function inside the lamda console? I'm still getting a key error for 'Records'.

Comment: It appears the problem was that I needed permission with CloudWatch logs. I solved the problem by giving admin access to the lamda function. I'm going to scale back by removing admin and finding the right permission set needed.

Comment: Every AWS Lambda function should be assigned the `AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole` policy. See: [AWS Lambda execution role - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-intro-execution-role.html)